# how do I use a blob read from a file in an if/else statement?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to read a character from a localhost file (a downloaded html file) and use it in an if/else statement.

This is code I found online with only modest modifications.  It successfully targets the specified character and displays it when clicking one of the buttons, but when I try to use it in the if/else statement (by clicking the action button), I have no success.  What should happen, is the if/else statement uses the character to determine how to ammend the window.open statement in the var mywin.  I'm not sure how to use the blob in the if/else statement. Thank you for your help.

'function job()' is where I am stuck.

Here is the code to the source file (a downloaded html webpage)

```
 <small><a href="http://192.168.089/30000"></a></small><a href="http://192.168.089/30000/0101101001011010">0101101001011010</a><p>
```

Here is the code of the html file I am writing that is trying to use the if/else statement.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<HTML>
<HEAD>
<script>
  function job(){
var action;
  if (blob = '0') {
    action = '06';
  } else {
    action = '05';
  } 
     var mywin = window.open('http://192.168.0.89/30000/' +action,'','');
      setTimeout(function() { mywin.close();}, 3000);
    }
  </script>
<style>
  #byte_content {
    margin: 5px 0;
    max-height: 100px;
    overflow-y: auto;
    overflow-x: hidden;
  }
  #byte_range { margin-top: 5px; }
</style>
<input type="file" id="files" name="file" /> Read bytes: 
<span class="readBytesButtons">
  <button data-startbyte="89" data-endbyte="89">Relay 1</button>
  <button data-startbyte="90" data-endbyte="90">Relay 2</button>
  <button data-startbyte="91" data-endbyte="91">Relay 3</button>
  <button data-startbyte="89" data-endbyte="104">All Relays</button>
  <button>entire file</button>
<input type=submit value='Action' onclick='job();' />
</span>
<div id="byte_range"></div>
<div id="byte_content"></div>
<script>
  function readBlob(opt_startByte, opt_stopByte) {
    var files = document.getElementById('files').files;
    if (!files.length) {
      alert('Please select a file!');
      return;
    }
    var file = files[0];
    var start = parseInt(opt_startByte) || 0;
    var stop = parseInt(opt_stopByte) || file.size - 1;
    var reader = new FileReader();
    // If we use onloadend, we need to check the readyState.
    reader.onloadend = function(evt) {
      if (evt.target.readyState == FileReader.DONE) { // DONE == 2
        document.getElementById('byte_content').textContent = evt.target.result;
        document.getElementById('byte_range').textContent = 
            ['Read bytes: ', start + 1, ' - ', stop + 1,
             ' of ', file.size, ' byte file'].join('');
      }
    };
    var blob = file.slice(start, stop + 1);
    reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
  }
  document.querySelector('.readBytesButtons').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {
    if (evt.target.tagName.toLowerCase() == 'button') {
      var startByte = evt.target.getAttribute('data-startbyte');
      var endByte = evt.target.getAttribute('data-endbyte');
      readBlob(startByte, endByte);
    }
  }, false);
</script>
```

Comment: What's this? `if (blob = '0') {`

Comment: @gcampbell  I was trying to use ' var blob = file.slice(start, stop + 1);' from later in the code. I'm sure it is not a proper use, but I am at a loss...

Comment: You probably need `==` or `===`.

Comment: @gcampbell I tried both == and ===.  At first I got "blob undefined" error, so I moved the code lower and included it in the main script `var blob = file.slice(start, stop + 1);
    reader.readAsBinaryString(blob);
var action;
  if (blob == '0000') {
    action = '06';
  } else {
    action = '05';
  } 
    var mywin = window.open('http://192.168.0.89/30000/' +action,'','');
      setTimeout(function() { mywin.close();}, 3000);
  }
  document.querySelector('.readBytesButtons').addEventListener('click', function(evt) {` I've tried == 0 =='0' ===0 ===0.  They all result in else. thx